# Do low temperatures cause problems installing new optical wiring or fixing broken optical cables by splicing?

Tags: fiber, cabling, optics

One of our supplier reported big problems splicing (using [this](https://www.alternetivo.cz/spojka-opticka-kabelova-odklopna-rady-rn-foc-pro-max-048-svaru-kompletni-vcetne-odklopnych-kazet-hrebenu-a-dalsiho-prislus-_d10184.html?catalog=stoitemunit&action=setlng&lngid=1&curid=14&)) a broken outdoor optical fiber cable when temperatures around or little bellow freezing point. They refuse to install new optical fiber wires when temperatures are not well above zero degrees.

The other supplier claims that even -10°C will not stop them from splicing optical wire and installing a new outdoor cable.

How can low temperatures cause troubles when fixing or installing optical cable outdoors? Does it differ by the type of cable used or something like that?

Comment: Do you mean "splicing" rather than "coupling"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming the technician is using Fusion splicing to connect the fibers, which they mostly do in my country, then there are strict temperatures to be complied with.

Splicing activity must be done in a very clean place to prevent dust or any contamination that affects the splicing process. The temperature of the place which the splicing process can take place may vary from 15º C to 28º C.

Although the fusion splicing machine can work at temperature between -10ºC and +5ºC and the closure can be installed at temperature between -1ºC and +45ºC, you still need to ensure that the splicing technician work in the optimum conditions to give the maximum efficiency.

Typically in Denmark where i live, they use a heated van, where they take the fiber inside via a special window and then work inside at +20ºC or more.

The splicing box you linked to says in the datasheet, that it can be installed at temperatures from -40 to 85℃, but it also clearly says: "*The product components shall withstand storage at temperatures of -40 to 85℃.*"

Fiber Optical Fusion Splicing Tutorial: https://www.fs.com/fiber-optical-fusion-splicing-tutorial-aid-295.html

Comment: I see, both places are in quarries with difficult conditions.I assume that the optimistic supplier should be able to bring the cable inside the building.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal i totally agree on that

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answer by user36472: I know that some of our contractors refuse to do ground works when temperatures are below 0 degrees celsius, since digging up fibers in frozen ground can be hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

In Finland we do installs also in winter. If the ground is frozen, it can be hard to dig, but also other cables may be in danger too. We do some splicing outdoors with home drop cables. Most of the problems may be moisture in the air, fog in the lenses of fusion splicer etc, when you bring splicing equipment from warm car to cold outside air.